# Difference between column type in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am really confused about the column in bootstrap. 
I study bootstrap but I cannot recognize the different between columns type.

```
 .col-md-4
 .col-xs-4
 .col-sm-4
 .col-lg-4
 .col-sm-offset-2
```

I understand what the numbers mean. and I understand the 12 column 
but what is the different between md, xs ....

I checked multiple website but cannot understand it well.
if you can give me details about it I would be pleasure.

Comment: md- for medium devices, xs-Extra small device, sm- small device, lg-Large devices

Comment: but what about the other ? and what do you mean by medium device ?

Comment: Go through it http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting. Medium devices are like Landscape tablets and medium desktops

Comment: himm okay I think now I understand the different between them, thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These different column types are used for making a website responsive. All the CSS which responds to screen sizes greater than **1200px** has the prefix *lg* (large) to it, screen sizes ranging from  **992px to 1199px** has the prefix *md* (medium), similarly sm (small) is for screen sizes **768px to 991px**. Anything lesser than **768px** falls under *xs* (extra small) category. Now if you have the code like this:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
```

In this case you will have 3 div's visible on a large screen, 2 div's on a medium screen, 2 on a smaller screen and 1 div on an extra small screen.
Each of the column type has been defined in a separate media query. So only one of the column type affects the div's width.

Comment: I guess the whole Idea is clear now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.These media queries are used to set CSS for different devices based on their resolution.

```
 /* Large desktops and laptops */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {

    }

    /* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    }

    /* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    }

    /* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {

    }

    /* Portrait phones and smaller */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The xs classes target mobile devices, sm targets tablets, md targets laptops and smaller desktop screens, and lg targets large desktop screens.

The best way to think about the new grid classes is that they work from mobile up, rather than from desktop down. This means by default your grid will stack from mobile up until the grid class breakpoint you’ve used is reached.

For example, using .col-lg-4 means your grid will stay stacked on mobile, tablet, and small desktop screens. Only until the large desktop breakpoint is reached will the grid go horizontal.